# Tracking different Contacts

Tags: record-type

This is one of the requirements and I’m confused with the use of RecordTypes –
I have a Contact and I want to track and report on the type of Contacts (Subscriber, Volunteer and Donor). So I decided to create Record types with these values and different page layouts based on needs. But now the issue is a Subscriber can be a Volunteer too (either two of them or a combination of all the three). In this case Record types won’t work as I can’t assign multiple record types to a record.
I’m not sure what to use in this case – a multi-select Picklist? Would I be able to track the Contacts and report on each type in this case? Is there any other feasible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-select picklist would do the job, but if you want to store some different info based on roles, you could create a custom object as a child of the contact record and call that role. That way you could assign multiple to a contact but reporting would definitely get more complicated, so I think the picklist is the best option.

If you wanted to support different layouts for input/editing then you could create a VF page driven by field sets which shows different sets based on the picklist value, but it's generally better to stick with standard functionality where you can.

Comment: The subscriber fields are just very limited. Its like a person clicks on "Subscribe" button on the website and they need to be tracked. Additionally they want to track which users are subscribed to which products (So 1 subscriber can be subscribed to multiple products). I am not sure but how would it be to create a custom object for subscribers? Just a thought.